# WearableRecyclerView OffsettingHelper.updateChild() not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I'm trying to build a `RecyclerView` which scales items based on their distance from center on screen like settings menu, following [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/features/wearable-recycler-view.html) from official "Android Developers".

Like this image:

[image]

The problem is `updateChild()` method never gets called at all. I tried using breakpoints to check if my offsetting helper actually is set and one more in updateChild, but everything is set right but not working.

Here is my code:

**wear/build.gradle**

```
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:10.2.0'
provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.0.0'
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
mRecyclerView = (WearableRecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);

mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
mAdapter = new MainAdapter(this, null);

mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mRecyclerView.setCenterEdgeItems(true);
mRecyclerView.setOffsettingHelper(new RecyclerOffsettingHelper());
```

**RecyclerOffsettingHelper.java**

```
public class RecyclerOffsettingHelper extends DefaultOffsettingHelper {

    /** How much should we scale the icon at most. */
    private static final float MAX_ICON_PROGRESS = 0.65f;

    private float mProgressToCenter;

    public RecyclerOffsettingHelper() {}

    @Override
    public void updateChild(View child, WearableRecyclerView parent) {
        super.updateChild(child, parent);

        // Figure out % progress from top to bottom
        float centerOffset = ((float) child.getHeight() / 2.0f) /  (float) parent.getHeight();
        float yRelativeToCenterOffset = (child.getY() / parent.getHeight()) + centerOffset;

        // Normalize for center
        mProgressToCenter = Math.abs(0.5f - yRelativeToCenterOffset);
        // Adjust to the maximum scale
        mProgressToCenter = Math.min(mProgressToCenter, MAX_ICON_PROGRESS);

        child.setScaleX(1 - mProgressToCenter);
        child.setScaleY(1 - mProgressToCenter);
    }
}
```

Is there anything I have missed from tutorial or did wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try, implementing the first two requirement, use `WearableRecyclerView` as your main container in the relevant XML layout and Set the `setCenterEdgeItems(boolean)` method to `true`. You can also add logs if any.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot Yes I used WearableRecyclerView as the main container and also made `setCenterEdgeItems(boolean)` true, like the code i have added, but no luck. And I'm afraid there is no significant log or error to add :(

Comment: I'm currently having the exact same problem, did you figure anything out?

Comment: @Marc see my posted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of googling and struggle I got the reason.

I decompiled `WearableRecyclerView` class and weirdly found no use of the `mOffsettingHelper` instance set by `setOffsettingHeler()` method, except in a private class named `OffsettingLinearLayoutManager` which extends `LinearLayoutManager` and will be set strictly to the recycler view on the Constructor method. So if you set you own layout manager in your code, the OffsettingHelper will get no use.

So I came up with a workaround and created my own layout manager to override `scrollVerticallyBy` and `onLayoutChildren` methods to call `updateChide` on `mOffettingHelper` object.

Here is the working code of my custom `LayoutManager`:

```
public class OffsettingLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
    private WearableRecyclerView mWearableRecyclerView;

    public OffsettingLinearLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public OffsettingLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    public OffsettingLinearLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    public void attachRecyclerView(WearableRecyclerView wearableRecyclerView) {
        this.mWearableRecyclerView = wearableRecyclerView;
    }

    public void detachRecyclerView() {
        this.mWearableRecyclerView = null;
    }

    public int scrollVerticallyBy(int dy, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int scrolled = super.scrollVerticallyBy(dy, recycler, state);
        this.updateLayout();
        return scrolled;
    }

    public void onLayoutChildren(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.onLayoutChildren(recycler, state);
        if(this.getChildCount() != 0) {
            this.updateLayout();
        }
    }

    private void updateLayout() {
        if(mWearableRecyclerView != null && mWearableRecyclerView.getOffsettingHelper() != null) {
            for(int count = 0; count < this.getChildCount(); ++count) {
                View child = this.getChildAt(count);
                mWearableRecyclerView.getOffsettingHelper().updateChild(child, mWearableRecyclerView);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: Do not forget to use `attachRecyclerView` method to set your `WearableRecyclerView` instance.

Hope it helps somebody.